# Get all records that has_one polymorphic recrd

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations, has-one

How can I create a scope that fetches all Jobs that have one Jsoon?

```
  #Job
  has_one :jsoon, as: :jsoonable, dependent: :destroy


  def self.hasjsoon
    where(joins(:jsoon))
  end


#Console:
Job.hasjsoon
```

Gives the error

```
Unsupported argument type: #<Job::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007f9e804936c8> (Job::ActiveRecord_Relation))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `where` to fetch all Jobs that have one Jsoon

This is enough

```
  def self.hasjsoon
    joins(:jsoon)
  end
```